# How can i transpose the row to col in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark

i am using pyspark 2.4.7 and i have a table like this :
+--------------------------+-----+
|                             feature|count|
+--------------------------+-----+
|                                      a|19386|
|                                      b|14734|
|                                      c|12815|
|                                      d| 4823|
+--------------------------+-----+

since swapaxes is not able to use, may i know how can i revise the table like this:
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| bin1_value|bin1_count| bin2_value|bin2_count|bin3_value|bin3_count| bin4_value| bin4_count|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|                 a|       19386|                b|       14734|                 c|        12815|               d|          4823|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+

Comment: do you have a column that says `bin1`, `bin2`, etc.?

Comment: see [`pivot()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot.html#pyspark-sql-groupeddata-pivot) in spark.